# Postgresql timestamp and NULL difference

Tags: postgresql, datetime, null, timestamp

I'm novice in PostgreSQL. I have a column timestamp without time zone named `FailureTime`. At the beginning it has NULL value.

When `SELECT` I need to get all entries that has `current_timestamp - FailureTime > interval '7'`.

But when `FailureTime` is NULL the result of operation is NULL.
Can I cast NULL to **ZERO** value or somehow get just `current_timestamp` as result of the operation?

Comment: Why don't you add `FailureTime IS NOT NULL` in your "WHERE" clause ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
current_timestamp - coalesce(FailureTime, current_timestamp) > interval '7'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude `NULL` elements by specifying something like:

```
SELECT ... 
WHERE (FailureTime IS NOT NULL) 
AND (current_timestamp - FailureTime > interval '7')
```